# vim: how to format wrong json

Tags: json, vim

I need to copy data from mongodb cli, for example,

```
{ "_id" : "95945f53-ae0d-4337-b5cc-af44e230b964", "field1" : "value1", "field2" : "value2", "field3" : "value3", "field4" : false, "createdTime" : NumberLong("1629562382798"), "updatedTime" : NumberLong("1629562382798")}
```

and format it like this:

```
{
   "_id":"95945f53-ae0d-4337-b5cc-af44e230b964",
   "field1":"value1",
   "field2":"value2",
   "field3":"value3",
   "field4":false,
   "createdTime":NumberLong("1629562382798"),
   "updatedTime":NumberLong("1629562382798")
}
```

I would like to be able to format it in vim or nvim editor. I found a few ways how to do it:

1. `:%!jq` returns `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:`
2. `:%!python -m json.tool` returns `No JSON object could be decoded`
3. https://github.com/tpope/vim-jdaddy says `invalid json`
   so all of them requires valid json.

When I format it in vscode with embedded tool (right click then choose "format code") it works fine.
Is there a way do the same in vim or nvim?

UPD:
there are more complex example with embedded objects

```
{ "_id" : "95945f53-ae0d-4337-b5cc-af44e230b964", "field1" : "value1", "field2" : "value2", "field3" : "value3", "field4" : false, "createdTime" : NumberLong("1629562382798"), "updatedTime" : NumberLong("1629562382798"), "object": { "_id" : "95945f53-ae0d-4337-b5cc-af44e230b964", "field1" : "value1", "field2" : "value2", "field3" : "value3", "field4" : false, "createdTime" : NumberLong("1629562382798"), "updatedTime" : NumberLong("1629562382798")}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can insert line breaks by replacing the commas:

```
:%s/,/,^M/g
```

and then add the indentations and the two remaining line breaks for the opening and closing braces manually.

(type <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> for `^M`)

Adding indentation can for example be done by selecting all lines in visual line mode (<kbd>Shift-v</kbd>) and then pressing <kbd>></kbd>.

Comment: `\r` is quicker and slightly more intuitive than `<C-v><CR>`.

Comment: the solution is OK for my small example, but if there are lots nested objects then I need to indent each of them :'( it is better to start vscode to format json with two clicks then

Comment: @АлександрБ "the right tool for the job".

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
:%s/,/,\r\t/g | s/}/\r&
```

Comment: in more complex example embedded objects are not indented { "_id" : "95945f53-ae0d-4337-b5cc-af44e230b964", "field1" : "value1", "field2" : "value2", "field3" : "value3", "field4" : false, "createdTime" : NumberLong("1629562382798"), "updatedTime" : NumberLong("1629562382798"), "object": { "_id" : "95945f53-ae0d-4337-b5cc-af44e230b964", "field1" : "value1", "field2" : "value2", "field3" : "value3", "field4" : false, "createdTime" : NumberLong("1629562382798"), "updatedTime" : NumberLong("1629562382798")}}